# PHP exec command on local server - Why doesn't this work?

Tags: php, apache, exec

I wanted clipboard access for a web app that I built for my own use on my local server, and I came up with this:

First a batch file that reads from another file:

```
clip < %1
```

and then in my PHP file:

```
exec("mybatch.cmd $file_with_text_to_be_copied");
```

no return variable needed, just straight execute...

No error in any log, but it just doesn't work.

I'm not surprised it doesn't work, given the security around clipboards, but I can't figure out why - how does chrome or Apache or whoever even know whats I'm doing?

I even tried something I read online about changing the Apache service account to being run by another account user (I think it was the system account - can't remember - but it was whatever I read online)
but no change...

Windows machine by the way - just in case that got missed.

Comment: It's hard to say why it does not work like you want it to work. Probably because there is no command called `clip` on the windows system?

Comment: Have you tried `passthru("clip < test")`? Does `clip < test` in the command line work? Have you tried executing another cmd file without parameters that does something harmless which the system should allow?

Comment: Haven't tried passthru... I will.  clip < test doesn't work unless test is a file.  If test is a file it works.  And yeah, all normal exec commands work such as mkdir, move, rmdir, etc.

Comment: To hakre:  What you say is not true.

Comment: @user1167442    Check server's error log - it might give the idea about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clipboard is a property of the session, so the clipboard you use with ctrl-c and friends on your desktop session is not the same, as the clipboard your webserver sees.

So without any helper app (running in your session) this is not possible.

BTW: It is good, this is not possible. Think over that, until you believe it.

Comment: @hakre: This perfectly confirms what I say: WITHOUT A HELPER APPLICATION WITH ACCESS TO ONE SESSION you cannot see its clipboard in another - in this case the terminal services are the helper application exporting the clipboard, and the RDP client is consuming it.

Comment: Ouch so much caps. And yay, that's why I added it. Problems with comments?

Comment: No problem at all. Pleading guilty on using THIS instead of **this** for emphasis

Comment: I've noticed that to be true sometimes when copying and pasting regularly...but it also does work most of the time...like if I copy my url and paste it into notepad.  Why is that different?

Comment: Rick--I don't know if you'll see this, but I just reread this, and you said "Without a helper app".  Can you give me an example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the system() function ? use system to display the output. Then you can find a way to solve possible errors.

Example with system function:

```
$response = system('ls -al', $return);
echo $response . "<br />" . $return;
```

Comment: `ls -al` is a universal command, that is not session specific (apart from being quite unusual on Windows)

Comment: it was just a sample. When using exec() - "If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends."

Comment: Perhaps it works, try: 
$temp = exec("mybatch.cmd", $file_with_text_to_be_copied);

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot access the clipboard like that. I would suggest making a simple JS script that actually reads your clipboard and the make a simple AJAX call to a back-end function (passing in the clipboard as a parameter) and then do whatever you need with it.

However, some browsers might limit access to the clipboard via JS.

Comment: I agree that I <b>shouldn't</b> be able to do that, but I can't understand why I can't.  As far as the browsers managing the clipboard with js, I can't see how the browser would have knowledge that I was accessing the clipboard from a function called from the browser